# onSync Event and its properties

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, methods

Hello People of Stackoverflow, I am using a persistent SharedObject for Adobe Media Server to store and share date in real-time for multiple clients. I am using the SyncEvent to dispatch any event that has been updated. 
Reading through the documerntation the SyncEvent contains numerous properties. What i want to achieve is to use remote shared object to store a list of people who are online when one client disconnects all the other clients listed will be updated of the disconnection. 
Adobe docs unfortunately doesnt provide any examples how to do this.
Would the best approach be to create a changeList array that contains properties of all members then execute a loop?
Or can anyone suggest any other method?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The changelist property of the event contains only the properties that got changed. So, if your shared object contains the list of ids, you should be able to get what you achieve.

Note, that the notification is done for the top level properties stored in the shared object. So, what you want would probably look like:

```
idSo.setProperty("1", true);
```

while adding. To remove the user, you should use:

```
idSo.setProperty("1", null);
```

To reassert, having

```
idSo.setProperty("ids", <array of ids>)
```

would send the whole array when it's updated. So, this would be a bad approach

This sync event would be sent to all the connected shared objects.